A question is made during programming. When is it an implementation and when is it applied computer science question?
During programing, I come up with some questions. For example, What is the difference between a DOM and a syntax tree?, tagged with parsers and syntax-trees.
Reading this article What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center - Computer Science Stack Exchange, I don't see where it directly mentions about this. I think the question may be classified as "programming language semantics, formal methods", but I'm not sure.
Most off-topic example questions in Are programming questions in scope on CS.SE? tie to a specific language, while my question is about web technology in general. And I think any computer technology is applied computer science.
The ACS Applied Computer Science journal lists its subject areas (categories) as: Computer Science, Information Systems, Industrial and Manufacturing Engineering, Mechanical Engineering, Biomedical Engineering, Economics, Econometrics, Management. I guess web technology is a sub area of Industrial and Manufacturing Engineering?
Some say that questions about implementations aren't on-topic. I understand that. But then, what is the difference between "implementing" and "applying"? Isn't that applying CS requires you to implementing a CS theory into code? Can you give some example?

Parsers are generally on-topic, although implementation details of them usually not. I think the question you posted is fine.

I've slightly edit the question to reflect this. When is it an implementation and when is it applied computer science question?

I think it's on-topic, assuming it is about concepts rather than code or implementations.
I generally discourage "What is the difference between X and Y?" questions.  My experience is that they often aren't an ideal match for the goals of this site.  If you understand X and Y, you usually should be able to answer that yourself.  If there is some specific aspect about X or Y you don't understand, it would be best to ask about that specific aspect.  If you don't have any clue about X or Y, it would be better to first do some research on X and Y, then ask about something specific you don't understand.
If you do ask, please make sure to define what you mean by a "DOM parser", and where you encountered it.  That phrase is new to me.  I don't understand what "what are more" means, so please explain that aspect of your question as well.

the question has been asked. Is it good?

what is the difference between "implementing" and "applying"? Isn't that applying CS requires you to implementing a CS theory into code? Can you give some example?

In my opinion, the question is on-topic, using mainly parsers, but could also be formal-grammar or any other tag about grammars.
What is off-topic is a question about a particular piece of code.
As an example, what we don't want is:

Hi, I have this algorithm that I must implement, here is my code in Python, but it doesn't work can somebody help me debug it?

What is perfectly ok:

Hi, I have this broad question about programming languages, not related to a specific program, for example, what are the pros and cons of compiling and interpreting?


How about a question like this? "During working on this code [insert code...], I find the documentation is confusing. The terms are used differently from my understanding from other source. Is it correct that it should have written like [insert text...]?"

@Ooker I am not sure, that seems to be a bit too specific about a certain programming language, and not about concepts.

I ask a separate quetion on this. Hope to see you there
